# ReactJS: lifecycle methods in a class or hooks in functional component with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, lifecycle, react-props

I have a hard time to solve problem with my code where I need to use lifecycle methods or hooks in a functional component.

Currently I have handled as lifecycle methods and code looks in a simple way like:

```
class Users extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    handleScroll(event) {
        let headers = document.getElementsByClassName("rt-thead");
        for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            headers[i].scrollLeft = event.target.scrollLeft;
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this._tBodyComponent = document.getElementsByClassName("rt-tbody")[0];
        this._tBodyComponent.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._tBodyComponent.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
    }

    render(){
        return(
         <div><UsersTable {...this.props}/></div>
        );
     }
}
```

that works almost fine till I want to access passed props in the `UsersTable` component.

At that point I have decided to rewrite that class to functional component which looks something like:

```
const Users = props => {

        ....

        return(
         <div><UsersTable {...props}/></div>
        );

}
```

and then inside the `UsersTable` table component add hooks as

```
const handleScroll = (event) => {
    let headers = document.getElementsByClassName("rt-thead");
    for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        headers[i].scrollLeft = event.target.scrollLeft;
    }
}

const UsersTable = props => {

    ...

    //componendDidMount
    useEffect(() => {
        this._tBodyComponent = document.getElementsByClassName("rt-tbody")[0];
        this._tBodyComponent.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll.bind(null, event));
    }, []);

    //ComponentWillMount
    useEffect(() => {
        this._tBodyComponent.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll.bind(event));
        return () => {
            this._tBodyComponent.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll.bind(event));
        }
    }, [])

    ....

}
```

but that is crashing on compilation for `Unexpected use of 'event'` or undefined `_tBodyComponent`

My question is if it worth to rewrite class to functional component to get passed props to child component or I'm doing there something wrong or if so how to handle properly scroll event in the component as hooks?

Comment: I think you're confusing stateless components with functional components. Stateless are components (can be both class or functional) without a state. Functional are components which are written as a function.

Comment: @Phoenix1355 Good point. I will update my question

Comment: I don't have a specific answer to this question, but I'd suggest maybe looking into Refs using the `useRef` hook. You're accessing DOM elements using the document methods, which sort of defeats some of the purposes of React. You could most likely achieve the exact same functionality using React Refs, while actually keeping the logic inside your react components without it being anti-pattern. And it would most likely simplify your issue and maybe even reveal a solution.